# How to set up data validation list for different columns in a worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble setting up data validation lists for different columns and that part in the code below is causing error and setting up correctly. Please review code below. I am also trying the lock the columns A and B and set up data validation lists for columns G and H. The source for data validation lists for columns G and H are on different sheets.

```
  Public Sub Button1_Click()

  ActiveSheet.Unprotect  



Dim sQry As String
Dim iRows As Integer
Dim iCols As Integer
Dim SQL As String



On Error GoTo ErrHandler




Call ClearExistingRows(4)


Call DBConnection.OpenDBConnection


Dim rsMY_Resources As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsMY_Resources = New ADODB.Recordset

SQL = "SELECT EmpID, EName, [Grouping], CCNum, CCName, ResTypeNum, ResName, Status from Employee_FTE Order by Status"



rsMY_Resources.Open SQL, DBConnection.oConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
If rsMY_Resources.EOF = True Then
    MsgBox ("No record found in database")
    Exit Sub
End If


iRows = 3
For iCols = 0 To rsMY_Resources.Fields.Count - 1
    ActiveSheet.Cells(iRows, iCols + 1).Value = rsMY_Resources.Fields(iCols).Name
Next
ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(iRows, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(iRows, rsMY_Resources.Fields.Count)).Font.Bold = True

iRows = iRows + 1
ActiveSheet.Range("A" + CStr(iRows)).CopyFromRecordset rsMY_Resources

iRows = rsMY_Resources.RecordCount


rsMY_Resources.Close:
Set rsMY_Resources = Nothing

Call DBConnection.CloseDBConnection



MsgBox (CStr(iRows) + " records have been retrieved from the database!")

 ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="listdata", RefersTo:= _
"='Data Sources'!$F$3:$F$4"
With Range("H4:H100")
With .Validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=listdata"
 End With
 End With

 ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="listdata1", RefersTo:= _
"='ResNameSheet'!A:A"
With Range("G4:G100")
With .Validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=listdata2"
End With
End With

Columns("C:H").Select
Selection.Locked = False
ActiveSheet.Protect

Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
MsgBox (Error)

End Sub
```

Thanks,
Hema

Comment: *"that part in the code below is causing error"* : on which line and what is the error message?

Comment: This part of the code below is giving an error "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="listdata1", RefersTo:= _
    "='ResNameSheet'!$A$1:$A$25"
    With Range("G4:G100")
    With .Validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula2:="=listdata1"
    End With
    End With

Comment: The data validation for column H seems to be working fine though!

Comment: Please don't put this useful information in the comments. [edit] your post instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the old validation before adding a new one with the same type. As a good practice, always `.Delete` old validation rule before `.Add`ing one unless you have a reason.

Also you had some typos between `listdata1` and `listdata2`. Notice you don't need nested `With`, just one.

```
  With Range("G4:G100").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=listdata1"
  End With

  With Range("H4:H100").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=listdata"
  End With
```